# R & figshare: corrupt zip when downloaded in R

Tags: r, unzip

I'm trying to make my research reproducible storing the data at [figshare](https://figshare.com).
Something strange happens when I download and unzip the data in R.
[here is the zip](https://dx.doi.org/10.6084/m9.figshare.3085210.v7)
If I download it manually, it opens ok; but when I try to get it with an `R` script, the downloaded archive is corrupt. Any ideas where is the problem?

---

the code to reproduce my error

```
url <- 'https://ndownloader.figshare.com/files/4797355'
path <- 'test/missing_data_raw.zip'

ifelse(file.exists(path1), yes = 'file alredy exists', no = download.file(url1, path1))

unzip(zipfile = path1,exdir = 'test')
```

Comment: Are you assigning the value of `ifelse()` to `path1`?

Comment: you can try `download.file(url, path, method="wget")` or `download(url,path,method="curl")`

Comment: @fishtank Neither `method="wget"` nor `method="curl"` helped. But `mode='wb'` did the trick. Thanks for good will!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try setting the download mode to binary explicitly:

```
url <- 'https://ndownloader.figshare.com/files/4797217'
path1 <- tempfile(fileext = ".zip")
if (file.exists(path1))  'file alredy exists' else download.file(url, path1, mode="wb")
unzip(zipfile = path1,exdir = tempdir())
```

Comment: I am still getting this error after using `mode = "wb"`.

Comment: As am I. Can we bump this to get a full solution?